# What is the best way to have the user select multiple images from a list of images?

Tags: mobile

The project I'm working on requires the user to select images corresponding to sports, which will help in filtering the match schedules according to the users requirement.

I need help in deciding the kind of user experience I want the customer to have. A simple tick mark on the top-right of the image after selection and removal on deselection is just not what I'm looking for as I believe that it is a redundant way to ask the user to select his preferences. Surely, there is a better way to deal with this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Roughly what size are these images?  Square thumbnails?  Do you have a preferred layout?  And roughly how many images?  ... I ask because it may make the difference  between a vertical scrolling listbox, horizontal scrolling listbox, a 3x3 table of images, etc

Comment: I was thinking of going for a 3x3 box layout with square thumbnails.. But instead of that, something like dragging the icons and placing them in a list below, maybe? So that the 3x3 box can populate with the remaining images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Long press to enable selection mode :**

*User will tap to view a image (do you have this feature ?)

User will long press on a image to enable selection mode, (when this mode is on) user then tap on other images to select multiple images.

This is most convenient process of multiple selection in smartphones in modern day OS.*